Pass query parameters to component service via routing
Background

I have 2 routes with differing query params
1) default route: '' (with query params id1)
2) alternate route: 'alternate' (with query params id1, id2, id3)

These 2 routes will go to the same component.

That component has a service to fetch data

The service requires the params to fetch data

The service instance is DI'd in by routing


export const MY_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./common.component').then((mod) => mod.CommonComponent),
    providers: [{ provide: AbstractService, useClass: Service1 }],
  },
  {
    path: 'alternate',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./common.component').then((mod) => mod.CommonComponent),
    providers: [{ provide: AbstractService, useClass: Service2 }],
  },
];

Service1 and Service2 are derived from AbstractService which has a flexible enough signature for getData to allow for differing query param availability per route, id1 or id1, id2, id3
export abstract class AbstractService {  
  abstract getData(
    args: Partial<{ id1: string; id2: string; id3: string }>
  ): Observable<TheData[]>;
}

This works well. However I'd like to change the abstract class contract to simply expose an observable like below
export abstract class AbstractService {  
  abstract data$: Observable<TheData[]>;
}

The problem
This introduces a problem. What is the best way now to provide the query parameter data to Service1 and Service2? Can I handle this by adding a constructor argument to Service1 and Service2 and resolving this somehow at the routing level using useFactory to generate the appropriate Service?
Stackblitz
Stackblitz demo

Modify your abstract service to accept optional parameters using ?: of typescript.
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { TheData } from '../models';

export abstract class AbstractService {
  abstract data$: Observable<TheData[]>;
  abstract getData(
    id1: string,
    id2?: string,
    id3?: string
  ): Observable<TheData[]>;
}

Then we can use the same approach of providing services and the http call will alternate between the two data.
Stackblitz Demo

If you see the original post the contract for AbstractService will change to only expose the Observable. The idea being that the common component can then simply subscribe to it rather than invoking a method call on the service. The solution you have provided is looking to extend getData() when the intent is to remove it. Thanks

@Fred2020 without setting the parameters to the service, how can you expect the API call to happen? this is the proper solution, the component must configure the service with the parameters

This is the question that is posed. Is it possible to somehow pass the parameters as an object to the service constructor during routing? For example, and this is not fully thought out, could I modify the routing to add a factory and that factory might be able to pass the query params during the creation of the service?

@Fred2020 when a junior dev looks at your code, which method makes sense, I also want you think about that, doesn't it seems complicated when there is an easier method like just calling a method, I'll delete my answer but give it a thought

I hear what you are saying, it's a fair point.
